# ClistView.xxx on yii 1 give notice property error not defined

Tags: php, yii

i want show comment data, but i have an error :

"Property "CListView.dataprovider" is not defined." whats wrong with my code? i have googling but still get the reason why that notice show.

here is my controller function :

```
  public function actionView($id,$c)
  {

 $modelviewedtopic=$this->loadModel($id,$c);

if($modelviewedtopic){
$modelviewedtopic->viewed=$modelviewedtopic->viewed+1;
$modelviewedtopic->save();
}

 $modelforumcoment=new ForumComment;

 $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
 $criteria->condition = 'id_forum_topic=:id_forum_topic';
 $criteria->params = array(':id_forum_topic'=>$id);

  $dataprovider=new CActiveDataProvider('ForumComment',array(
  'criteria'=>$criteria,
    'sort'=>array(
   'defaultOrder'=>'update_date ASC',
        ),
));

   $this->render('view',array(
   'model'=>$this->loadModel($id,$c),
    'modelforumcoment'=>$modelforumcoment,
   'dataprovider'=>$dataprovider,
  ));
 }
```

and here is my view :

```
  $comment = ForumComment::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('id_forum_topic'=>$model->id_forum_topic,'userid'=>Yii::app()->user->id));
  $total_comment = count($comment); 
   $widget = $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView',array(
   'id'=>'commentlist', 
   'loadingCssClass'=>'',
   'afterAjaxUpdate'=> 'reloadeditable', 
   'dataprovider'=>$dataprovider,
   'enableHistory' => true,
   'emptyText'=>'<b>No Comments</b>',
   'summaryText'=>'',
   'itemView'=>'_view_comment',
     )); 
  Editable::attachAjaxUpdateEvent($widget); 

  Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('reloadeditable', "
  function reloadeditable(id, data) {
   if('$total_comment' == 0){
    location.reload();
   }

   }
 ");
```

whats wrong with my code?

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'dataprovider'=>$dataprovider
```

you have to change to

```
'dataProvider'=>$dataprovider
```

because the variable name is case-sensitive

Comment: i just change it, now the error notice say this " Property "CListView.enableHistory" is not defined."  what is "enableHistory" on clistview? when i comment it, it works well

Comment: Which Yii version do you use?

enableHistory property available since v1.1.11

Comment: i used yii 1.1.13 sir

Comment: oh i sorry. when i check it, my app still use yii 1.1.10. so, what should i do?

Comment: You have to upgrade your version yii to the latest release or don't use enableHistory property